# Constraints : can i melt grams and calories and % as constraints?

Tags: pulp

Sorry for this begginer question !

Let's say i have 4 ingredients :

```
              price       calorie(?)  fat(g)   calcium(mg)  good(%) 
x1 Apple     1 $          72            0.8        159         75% 
x2 Mais      0.5 $        88            3.2        3.3         60% 
x3 Bread     0.5 $        150           22.2       120         45% 
x4 Brocolis  0.48 $       35            0.4        80          80%
```

I need to minimize the meal cost, for now, it is ok .

```
min 1x1 + 0.5x2 + 0.5x3 + 0.48x4 .
```

My problem is about the constraints :

**Can I use different units of measure, at the same time, in the constraints  ?**

Am I allowed to melt calories(unknown) and fat(grammes) and calcium(mg) and per cents (%) ?
Because a gramme is not a milligramme, and I dont even know what is a calory .

Is it possible to mixe grammes and milligrammes and whatever as constraints, like for example a % ?

Do I have to convert each values before writing down all of the constraints ?

I doubt this can work, this is my example with 4 constraints :

```
   prob += lpSum([calories[f] * aliments_vars[f] for f in aliments]) >= 47.0, "caloriesMinIn?"
    prob += lpSum([fat[f] * aliments_vars[f] for f in aliments]) >= 3.0, "fatMinIngrammes"
    prob += lpSum([calcium[f] * aliments_vars[f] for f in aliments]) >= 24, "calciumMinInmilligrammes"
    prob += lpSum([good[f] * aliments_vars[f] for f in aliments]) >= 45, "goodMinInPercent"
```

Thanks !

Comment: your solution should work , AFAIK the constraints don't need the same UoM as they are evaluated separately and based on the dimensions of your input

Comment: Yes, as @TenaciousB has stated the constraints are each evaluated separately. The important thing is that each of the terms within a constraint have the same units - e.g. if you have calories on the left hand side it's also calories on the right hand side.

Comment: fyi the unit we generally use for calorie is called kcal or kcal/kg to be precise

Comment: Well ok, Tenacious B and Kabdulla, thanks a lot for your kind answers.